# Why is "shrimp" the plural of "shrimp"?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

When you talk about "shrimp" in the plural, there's no "s."
However, how can you explain it grammatically?

Comment: It's not fair to close-vote this as it's a genuine question -- what is the answer? Is there an answer, for that matter?

Comment: kih, a good question can suffer if the asker does not show adequate background effort. Have you tried to find an answer before asking? What happened? What did you/ didn't you find? What do you think could be a possible 'grammatical explanation'?

Comment: Another example: series is both singular and plural.

Comment: There are at least two questions hidden here. (1) Does the noun _shrimp_ have two plural forms, _shrimp_ as well as _shrimps_ ? (2) Why do we say '... shrimp is off the menu' rather than 'a shrimp is off the menu' – and is 'shrimps are off the menu' acceptable? And probably (3) Can you explain the answer to (1), and (4) 'are (2) and (3) connected?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - If you moved those from your comment into edits into the question, I'd vote to reopen.

Comment: If you look at past questions, two or three years ago, and the volume of answers they generated along with their curious facts and observations; nowadays many would be closed as being "general reference". This short-sightedness of ELU will spell its end. People have genuine questions about the English language and come here to ask. What does the community do? Snub these questions as not being high-brow enough.

Comment: I for one did not know that shrimp was a mass noun, I've always heard and said, shrimps, so what about prawns? I've read that prawns and shrimps are often interchangeable, is "prawn" a mass/uncountable noun too?

Comment: @JR I'm not sure I could break it down into a single question - it would have to be as general as 'what senses do 'shrimp' and 'shrimps' carry in various usages?' - and might not be acceptable.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: 
Try a Google search for "shrimp is off the menu" and then one for "prawn is off the menu". I don't know how significant the results are, but their ratio is quite compelling. It just seems to show how idiosyncratic usage can be. (Yes, I chose the mass version for 'usage'.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I also checked: "shrimp is good" vs "prawn is good" (to avoid instances of "shrimp" is a word/the term etc.) and "shrimps are" vs "prawns are". I have a feeling that "shrimp" as a mass noun is more commonly used in the southern states of the US. I am tempted to edit the question, but judging on my present performance, I'd probably give it the kiss of death. You try!

Comment: Funnily enough when I typed shrimps, Google suggested "Shrimps are insects" and for the singular, "shrimp is an abomination" Possible question: **Where (and why) are shrimps sometimes an uncountable noun?** And then include "shrimp is off the menu" and/or "shrimp is good for you" vs plural forms.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: I've posted the issues in a way that is certainly acceptable on the [Wordwizard](http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=21035) website (fewer constraints, which has pluses and minuses that everyone will disagree about, of course). If you look there and just choose the meat . . .

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks, good read. It seems that size is not really the determining factor whether a food is considered as a mass, as acutely observed by one. Why are peas, beans, and peanuts countable and not shrimp? Although, I will continue to say, shrimps. Maybe Italian shrimps are bigger than American's? :) (How awful would that sentence sound in the singular!)

Comment: This helping of shrimp only contains about seven shrimps.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/586484/2085).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some words may be either singular, plural, or uncountable, depending on how they are used in a particular context. That's just the way it is. There's really no *grammatical* explanation to it, although for some words, there may be historical explanations behind how their plurals are formed.

I should note, however, that "shrimp" is actually one of those words where the plural form may be "shrimp" *or* "shrimps", depending on the speaker's dialect.

> **shrimp** (*countable and uncountable*, *plural* **shrimp** or **shrimps**)
>
> —source: [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shrimp)

Comment: So, where is the 'reason'?

Comment: @Kris That's like asking 'Well, **is** the answer to (6 + 7) 10 or 11?' after the person addressed has just said 'Neither'.

Comment: There is a related article on alga/algae at the [“Blue-green algae is/are present in the lake”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94140/blue-green-algae-is-are-present-in-the-lake) thread .

Comment: I say shrimps, but sheep

Comment: As an AmE Midland speaker, the only time I've ever heard "shrimps" was in reference to multipe short people.

Comment: @T.E.D. Would you say 'There are two crabs and three shrimp in this tank'? Over here, I'd be surprised (but not over-surprised) not to hear both 'regular' plurals in this instance.

Comment: Can you give examples of 'singular, plural, [and] uncountable' usage here?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's exactly what I'd say. But to be fair, I live in the middle of the continent. Such a sentence is highly unlikely from me, and the folks who do actually crabbing and shrimping in the USA tend to have a different dialect than I. I can't vouch for how they'd say it.

Comment: ...for example, I tend to pronounce "barbed wire" more like "bob war". That's not because my native AmE Midland says it that way (it doesn't), but because whenever the word ever came up in conversation for me when I was growing up, I was speaking with someone who spoke a southern accent. So I'm inclined to think asking an AmE Midland speaker about the pronunciation of terms that are ocean related isn't liable to be very enlightening. :-)

Comment: @T.E.D. Thank you. In Page last year (while on a 'Grand Circle' coach tour), my wife and I tried (and were delighted with the) tilapia. Wikipedia offers both plurals for this, but I don't think that I've personally ever heard 'tilapias'. Of course, it's not a sea-fish and not native to the UK. And it's still quite rare to see it offered here.

Answer (score 5):

In English we have mass nouns such as *wood* or *rice*. You cannot count a mass noun by putting a number in front of it (*two books*) or pluralize it by adding an *-s* (*lamps*). To indicate quantity you write  the unit of measure in front of the mass noun. For example, you would write "two cords of wood" or "ten feet of wood" or "two pounds of rice".

It seems the grammatical reasons for this are obscure. I've read several explanations of how it is but none that explicity give the reason why it is so.  I found the following online at [grammar.about.com](http://grammar.about.com/od/mo/g/massnounterm.htm):

> Is there a conceptual basis to the grammatical distinction between count nouns and mass nouns? One answer is that this grammatical distinction is, to a very large degree, semantically opaque and unprincipled . . .. In general, people learn which nouns are typically used as count nouns and which are typically used as mass nouns without any understanding of why these differences in syntax occur. Another answer is that the grammatical distinction between count and mass nouns is to a very large degree conceptually based. That is, when speakers use count nouns to refer to things they implicitly have something in mind that they are trying to communicate that is common across all uses of count nouns. A similar view applies to the use of mass nouns. A third answer, and the one that I propose, is that the count-mass noun distinction is to a very large degree conceptually based, but there are exceptions. Some exceptions do not seem to have a clear explanation, but others may occur because of competing communicative functions of language.

Here's [Wikipedia's take](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun#Relating_grammatical_number_to_physical_discreteness):

> In English (and in many other languages), there is a tendency for nouns referring to liquids (water, juice), powders (sugar, sand), or substances (metal, wood) to be used in mass syntax, and for nouns referring to objects or people to be count nouns. This is not a hard-and-fast rule; however, mass nouns such as furniture and cutlery, which represent more easily quantified objects, show that the mass/count distinction should be thought of as a property of the terms themselves, rather than as a property of their referents. For example, the same set of chairs can be referred to as "seven chairs" and as "furniture"; although both chair and furniture are referring to the same thing, the former is a count noun and the latter a mass noun. The Middle English mass noun pease has become the count noun pea by morphological reanalysis.
>
> For another illustration of the principle that the count/non-count distinction lies not in an object but rather in the expression that refers to it, consider the English words "fruit" and "vegetables". The objects that these words describe are, objectively speaking, similar (that is, they're all edible plant parts); yet the word "fruit" is (usually) non-count, whereas "vegetables" is a plural count form. One can see that the difference is in the language, not in the reality of the objects. Meanwhile, German has a general word for "vegetables" that, like English "fruit", is (usually) non-count: das Gemüse. British English has a slang word for "vegetables" that acts the same way: "veg" [rhymes with "edge"].
>
> In languages that have a partitive case, the distinction is explicit and mandatory. For example, in Finnish, join vettä, "I drank (some) water", the word vesi, "water", is in the partitive case. The related sentence join veden, "I drank (the) water", using the accusative case instead, assumes that there was a specific countable portion of water that was completely drunk.
>
> The work of logicians like Godehard Link and Manfred Krifka established that the mass/count distinction can be given a precise, mathematical definition in terms of quantization and cumulativity.

Comment: We've had a lot of this before, but +1 for bringing it all together.

Comment: Two cords of wood, three pieces of furniture, four strands of hair, but two what of sheep? Three what of deer? Four what of fish?

Comment: @BlessedGeek: But those aren't uncountable: we say *a sheep*, *two sheep*, and *sheep are*. That's different from *water*: we don't say **a water* **two water* or **water are* (except in the sense "a glass of water", which if a different (countable) sense of the word).

Comment: Exactly. So the reply should not correlate wood, or furniture or hair to sheep, or fish or deer.

Answer (score 3):

The reason?

When we talk about shrimp or fish in the singular but the referent is multiple, we are referring to it as a material in which the individuals are not visible or important. This is the same way that we talk about paper or meat, and as there is only one material it is singular. This is often the case where the thing being referred to is useful to us in some way. Food or drink for example.

An example of this is that we talk of a castle being built of stone, because we are not interested in the the individual stones, but would talk about a wheelbarrow full of stones being taken to the castle.

It is not clear cut though. Some people will talk about [a herd of elephant](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20herd%20of%20elephant&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), others a herd of elephants, and we have a flock of sheep but a herd of cows. One explanation for this is that sheep tend to run around in one mass in which the individuals are lost (the same as fish or shrimp) while cows spread out as individuals, but that would not explain the herd of elephant.

Comment: I know of some people who would (quite rightly) point out that this does not answer the OP's question. It does not give a 'grammatical' reason (as p.s.w.g. and ZZMike can be deduced to point out). However, I'm upvoting it because I think it addresses the 'question behind the question' better than those answers – I'd appreciate it if the favour was returned in future (the stance – the upvoting is far less important).

Comment: In what way is "we are referring to it as a material in which the individuals are not visible or important [..] as there is only one material it is singular." and "One explanation for this is that sheep tend to run around in one mass in which the individuals are lost (the same as fish or shrimp) while cows spread out as individuals" not a grammatical reason?

Comment: For the same reason that 'Colourless green ideas sleep furiously' is not ungrammatical. Grammar looks purely at the acceptability (often disputed) of sentence etc structure, not at whether the actual resulting string then makes sense, nor at how various accepted structures relate (or otherwise) to the details of the situation being described. I'd agree that semantics and syntax are too often kept too far apart.

Comment: As for 'stance'... I think the question asked should be answered. What is the problem with that? As most askers - and answerers -are not linguists I also resist the temptation to use it as an excuse to show off my linguistic training. Where background would be useful, fine, but even then I try to keep it simple. Use Ngram instead of COCA; avoid links or references to obscure research papers; avoid obscure technical terms if possible. That kind of thing.

Comment: Whether 'colourless green ideas sleep furiously' is grammatical is arguable. Perhaps you meant to say syntactically correct, but as it fails semantically the grammaticality depends on how you define grammar. Chomsky, by the way, used the sentence as an example of one that had never been spoken - not one that is 'grammatically correct' but nonsense - so you are kind of missing the point there. And where, in my post, is there anything resembling that?

Comment: But in the view of three (at least) of us, you have just answered a question-behind-a-question ('How can you explain this') rather than the overt ('how can you explain [this] grammatically') (answer  – 'There's really no grammatical explanation') and brought out some analysis I feel is interesting, sound, and probably appreciated by OP and others here. The 'appropriate level' problem is always going to be with us. Your answer above is both deep and accessible. I think that is in line with the spirit of this site – which is why I come here.

Comment: I think you are confusing syntax with grammar...

Comment: ["Colorless green ideas sleep furiously" is a sentence composed by Noam Chomsky in his 1957 Syntactic Structures as an example of a sentence that is grammatically correct, but semantically nonsensical.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorless_green_ideas_sleep_furiously) . I'm going to avoid discussions with you in future; some of your posts – perhaps most – contain valuable information and insights. But your 'you are kind of missing the point there' reveals character.

Comment: ... and in the second paragraph *of the same article* - "While the meaninglessness of the sentence is often considered fundamental to Chomsky's point, *Chomsky was only relying on the sentences' having never been spoken before.* " His argument was that in statistical analysis of discourse, the syntactically correct arrangement and the following random, syntactically incorrect arrangement would both be treated in the same way - zero results. That is why I say you are missing the point. Chomsky was not illustrating a meaningless sentence. He was illustrating an unspoken one.

Comment: I like this explanation, it's clear and it helps both native and non-native speaker also realize why the seemingly illogical mass noun, **hair**, is considered uncountable when attached to a person's head but countable when they are detached; e.g "She pulled out two grey hairs".

Answer (score 1):

There is also "fish" (singular) and "fish" (plural); "deer" and "deer".  I agree with p.s.w.g. that there is no grammatical explanation, but rather one of how word plurals are formed.

To make things even more complicated, the plural is also "fishes".   In U.S. English, it's "one fish, many fish".

Comment: No it's not. **fish** n. pl. fish or fish·es (AHD). I'll accept their take, as they claim to have surveyed usage.

Answer (score 1):

The most common plural form of "shrimp" happens to be the same as the singular.  Just like the singular and plural forms of "you", "sheep", "samurai", and many other words.