# What’s special about the word “fish”

Tags: collective-nouns, irregular-plurals, pluralia-tantum

When there are two or more carps, you can say “there are fish”, treating singular form of fish without plural suffix “s” as a plural, but I think normally it doesn’t apply to other nouns, is that correct? And is there linguistic category for words like this?

Comment: If you're going to answer, include this stuff, too: > "Scientists say alarming declines at the southern end of the fishes' range may be a sign of what's to come as waters warm farther north." (NYT) https://www.nytimes.com/2023/04/03/climate/salmon-fishery-closed-california.html

Comment: See also the [question about types of fish](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/256414/191178)

Comment: There's a bunch of mostly animal nouns with zero plurals: _sheep, salmon, fish, halibut, deer, squid, elk, moose_, etc. Some are herded, some are hunted, and there's lots of exceptions, too. It's just another bunch of irregular nouns. There are plenty of others.

Comment: Actually, "two carp" is more common than "two carps". Therre is a related question about fish and other animal plurals at: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/427805/why-a-stream-full-of-trout-but-not-a-stream-full-of-newt

Comment: See answers on invariant plurals (especially for animals) at [Why is the plural of 'deer' the same as the singular?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/188578/why-is-the-plural-of-deer-the-same-as-the-singular)