# Why is the plural of reindeer sometimes "reindeer"?

Tags: grammatical-number

Why is the plural of reindeer sometimes "reindeer"?

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reindeer) has the following etymology:

> From Middle English, from Old Norse hreindýri ‎(“reindeer”), from hreinn + dýr ‎(“animal”).

while the etymology of [deer](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deer) doesn't have any mention of Old Norse, so I assume knowing about the pluralisation of "deer" (from [Why is the plural of “deer” the same as the singular?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/188578/why-is-the-plural-of-deer-the-same-as-the-singular)) isn't sufficient to explain this.

Comment: The plural  of *deer* is usually *deer*.

Comment: Are you asking why the plural of *deer* is *deer*, and just using "reindeer" for your question to give it a seasonal touch? Or are you asking why *reindeer* follows the model of *deer* rather than forming its plural in *-s*?

Comment: I wonder if there's a hat in this, it's so... unusual for a high-rep user.

Comment: "Mongoose" and "moose" don't share the same pluralisation as "goose", nor does "fox" share the same pluralisation as "ox".

Comment: The plural of *moose* in English is *moose* but that is not because the Algonquian languages that gave us the word lacked a distinct plural form for it: in Ojibwe, for instance, singular is *mooz,* plural *moozag.*

Comment: *Dormouse* shares its plural with *mouse*. And the plural of *muskox* is *muskoxen*.

Comment: Goose, geese; moose, meese; mouse, mice; house, hice. What is not clear?

Comment: Excuse me a minute, the UPS guy just delivered a couple of boxen...

Comment: @Jim something made out of boxwood? https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/boxen#Etymology_1 (before looking it up, I only knew the "Etymology 2" version)

Comment: @PeterShor I've looked up the etymology of reindeer, and while it may be cognate with "deer", it doesn't look like it's directly formed from it. I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: You're expecting English speakers to figure out what plurals they use based on etymology? That works remarkably often, but I think being confused about *reindeer* is only to be expected.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm but Fox is not a kind of ox, and mongoose and moose are not a kind of goose (neither is any of these a kind of oose).  But a reindeer *is* (linguistically, at least) a kind of deer.  To put it another way, it's not that reindeer and deer are similar words, it's that the word deer is a component of the word reindeer.

Comment: The real question is "why is it sometimes *reindeers*?". Because *reindeers* is the rare one.

Comment: @PeterShor no, but you are.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm are there any old Norse words in English that are pluralized differently from their English cognates?  Can we really say that *-deer* from Norse and *deer* from Anglo-Saxon are different words?  Perhaps the English translated "reindeer" rather than borrowing it, or maybe the two etymological streams can be said to have merged.

Comment: OED says: The Germanic base of rein n.2 + the Germanic base of deer n.), with remodelling of the second element after deer n.

Comment: I think that all members of the deer family share the same behavior wrt plurals (plural has the same form as singular): deer, reindeer, moose, elk,...

Comment: @Drew Do you mean all members of the deer family speak the same language?

Comment: @ab2: Maybe not between generations. You know - those millenials.

Answer (score 1):

My Chambers English dictionary plainly states that 'deer' is derived from Old English 'deor' and the plural is 'deer'. The plural of reindeer is also reindeer. I don't think this is related at all to the other usages quoted such as: 'there are lion in these parts', 'there are tiger in these forests', 'man first discovered fire when lightning struck a fallen branch of oak'.

Comment: Would also apply to moose and sheep.

Answer (score -2):

I can find no reference to support this, but isn't the singular form of  many animal nouns used when they are being considered as a species, especially when they are being tracked, hunted or eaten?

"Look out! There are lion in these parts."

"I prefer rabbit to squirrel".

Comment: I don't think the wording of this is quite right. I'd say instead that the plural form is the same as the singular. (In a sentence like "Reindeer have four hooves," the word "reindeer" is technically plural, not singular, as shown by the plural verb agreement.)

Comment: @Sumelic - You're right, thanks. I'm not entirely happy with my edit, but it's better I think!

Comment: Both *lion* and *lions* can be used as a plural, but virtually [nobody](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lion%2Clions%2Cdeer%2Cdeers%2C+reindeer%2C+reindeers&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clions%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeers%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creindeer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creindeers%3B%2Cc0) uses the word *deers* or *reindeers* (as a plural or not).